# Totally, Completely, Fully or Entirely?

Tags: adverbs

I'd like to know which is which! I don't know if I can use them correspondingly or not.
Is there any rule or I have to remember expressions?

- You are totally/completely/entirely/fully correct.
- I totally/completely/entirely/fully agree with you.
- I totally/completely/entirely/fully forgot.
- and so on.

Comment: Don't think much! They all mean same.

Comment: They do all mean about the same thing, but if you said, "I fully forgot", that just doesn't sound right, so there is a difference. Personally, I think "completely" is the word I would use most often in all three of those situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They all have the same meaning.

*Totally* has a small chance of coming across as too informal (in AmE at least) due to [this phenomenon](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2005-07-20/features/0507190293_1_clueless-slang-amy-heckerling) which AFAIK is waning but still present.  Be careful to not overuse this word in formal situations.

*Fully* is probably the least commonly used of all these words and the one that most often could catch a listener off guard.  *Fully support* is an example (*I fully support the campaign*, etc.) I've heard used before, though.  I agree with @Keiki that *completely* is the most common word in this situation, though there is nothing wrong at all with *entirely*.